# Keras Tensor Reshaping Error when adding Flatten layer after Embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

this is the error I'm getting:

```
 Input to reshape is a tensor with 20480 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1124073472
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
tmp_model = Sequential()
tmp_model.add(Embedding(1000, 64, input_length=10))
tmp_model.add(Flatten())

input_array = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 10))

tmp_model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
output_array = tmp_model.predict(input_array)
```

I see no reason why I can't flatten after Embedding. 
You guys have any ideas?

(tensorflow backend, not sure if it matters. )

Comment: I tried your code and it worked perfectly. I'm on `Keras 2.1.2`

Answer (score 0):

Hobo way to solve this: 
instead of using Flatten(), I did

```
tmp_model.add(Reshape((64*10,))
```

to manually "flatten".

But surely, there's a reason why Flatten() didn't work!!!